# $\int_{A}f$ exists then $\int_{A}|f|$ exists and then $\int_{A}|f|$ > |$\int_{A}f$|

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have a real valued function $f$ on a subset $A$ of $E^n$.

$\int_{A}f$ exists.

**Edit:**
I am looking at trying to show $\int_{A}|f|$ exists and then I want to show that $\int_{A}|f|$ >= |$\int_{A}f$|.

At first I tried to assume that $A$ is a closed interval however I got stuck. I can not think of a case where $\int_{A}f$ exists and $\int_{A}|f|$ does not exist so I believe that one existing implies the other existing.This part I know to be true, but am stuck on the proof. However, why does $\int_{A}|f|$ > |$\int_{A}f$| true? Is there a case when it could be greater than equal? I am a little lost on the proof of this. Any help would be great!

Comment: Is this a Riemann or Lebesgue integral? Also, I assume you mean $\int_A|f| \geq |\int_A f|$.

Comment: The inequality *should* be 
$$
\int_A |f| \geq \left| \int_A f \right|
$$
equality occurs when $f \geq 0$.

Comment: Presumably, you mean $f:E^n \to \Bbb R$

Comment: It is a Riemann integral but I was asked strictly > and not >= which stumbled me

Comment: You need to be careful about what it means for $\int_A f$ to exists.  In the usual treatment of Lebesgue integration, we have
$$
\int_A f := \int_A f^+ - \int_A f^-
$$
and the integral only exists if the two integrals on the right exist and are not both infinity.  So, for example, $\sin(x)/x$ as a function on $\Bbb R$ should be considered non-integrable, even though its improper Riemann integral converges.

Comment: If this is meant to be a Riemann integral, then note that
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx
$$
converges, while 
$$
\int_0^\infty \left| \frac{\sin(x)}{x} \right|\,dx
$$
diverges.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom this was told to me in a Riemann integration context not Lebesgue

Comment: @timhardawayy then you've got a typo somewhere.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I think you are right it must be >= not >. I think he miscommunicated with me on this problem.